# Firebase Authentication-Reset password does not show any action- Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I wrote this reset password function, but the problem is when I open my reset password page and click on the "send" button I don't get any response

Here is my  HTML:

```html
<form id="forget_form" action="#" name="forget_form" method="POST">
<div class="data">
 <label> Email: </label>
 <input id="email_reset" type="text">
  </div>
<div class="btn">
 <div class="inner"> </div>
  <button onclick="reset()" id="forget_btn" type="submit">Send</button>
       </div>
 </form>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```js
function reset()
{    
const reset = document.querySelector('#forget_form');
reset.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const email_Forget = reset['email_reset'].value;
    if(email_Forget!="")
    {
        

    auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email_Forget).then(() => {
        alert('Password Reset Email Sent Successfully!');
        
       
    })
    .catch(error => {
        alert(error.message);
    })
    
}
else
{
    alert("Enter your email address");
}

  });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, the solution to this problem was very easy, I just need to change the name of the function, because I name my function '**reset()**' which is the name of the function that is already taken in javascript, so after I change the name of my function from **reset()** to **resetpasswors()** . The problem was solved and the function worked now.

Answer (score 0):

Your `reset` function is not calling any Firebase API yet. It instead attaches an event handler to an element in your HMTL:

```
function reset()
{    
const reset = document.querySelector('#forget_form');
reset.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
```

My guess is that you want to go without the `addEventListener` and simply do:

```
function reset() {    
    e.preventDefault();
    const email_Forget = reset['email_reset'].value;
    if(email_Forget!="") {
      auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email_Forget).then(() => {
        alert('Password Reset Email Sent Successfully!');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert(error.message);
      })
    
    }
    else {
      alert("Enter your email address");
    }
}
```

---

I find it easiest to troubleshoot these problems by stepping through my code in a debugger. For example, I recommend putting a `debugger` statement in your originla `reset` code and stepping though there:

```
function reset()
{
debugger;
const reset = document.querySelector('#forget_form');
reset.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
```

Comment: Hi Frank, in addition the button is of type `submit` => the form will probably be submitted before the Firebase method is triggered. (TBC since there is `e.preventDefault();`) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65932710/jquery-can-not-set-data-to-firebase/65935096#65935096

Comment: thanks, Frank, but I actually did call the Firebase API, at the bottom of the HTML page. Also, I did the same thing with sign in and sign up functions they worked fine except for the reset password which didn't give any response